# Click event of control in dynamically loaded usercontrol not firing in .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a aspx page with a placeholder in an update panel. The user control is attached to the placeholder depending the value of a dropdown on the page. The user control loads correctly, but it seems that the click event of the button is not firing. I've put a breakpoint in the .js file, but it never goes into the js function. Not sure if the javascript is even loaded.

The aspx page:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="UserControlTest.Page" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/TestUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="TestUserControl" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/testUserControl.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <h4>This is the page</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="selUserControl">Enquiry Type &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk pull-right" style="color:red"></span> </label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="selUserControl" CssClass="form-control reqrd" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selUserControl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divUserControl">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phUserControl" />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="selUserControl" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The aspx.cs page:

```
protected void selUserControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestUserControl uc = (TestUserControl)LoadControl("~/TestUserControl.ascx");
        uc.ID = "ucUserControl";
        phUserControl.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

The .ascx page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControlTest.TestUserControl" %>

<div>
    <h4>This is the User Control</h4>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="button" id="btnPress" class="btn" value="Press!" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnPress").click(function () {
        alert('Hi There from User Control');

    });
});
```

Comment: You need to use event delegation to bind functions to dynamically added elements. Look into jquery's on() method like $(document).on('click', '#btnPress', function(){ ..... Code here});

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. As it is a comment I cannot mark it as the answer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time your `js` is run, `#btnPress` doesn't exist on the page (or at least the original `#btnPress` doesn't. @DelightedD0D is right. I'd look into using event delegates and attaching them to your document. This way you can attach/detach as many `#btnPress` as you'd like and your clicks will bubble to document and be handled by the delegate.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnPress', function(){
  alert('Hi There from User Control');
});
```